# Choose two different years joined employees from table

Tags: oracle, informatica

In oracle for informatica, I am using the condition `to_char(hiredate, 'YYYY')=1981` and it is showing me all 1981 employees, if I want to see 1981 and 1982 employees together, which code is required?

Comment: As an aside: since the right-hand side will be a string, don't compare it to a number (`1981`); compare it to a string (`'1981'`).

Answer (score 0):

you could use a IN clause

```
where to_char(hiredate, 'YYYY') IN ( '1981', '1982')
```

Answer (score 0):

**Querying for a Set of Years on Date Column**

One could create a condition where you could cast the `hiredate` as a `char` and look for a set of years as follows:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    emp
WHERE
    TO_CHAR(hiredate,'YYYY') in ('1981', '1982')
    ;
```

This works for a small set of records fairly well.

For a larger, non-trivial set of records, especially when there maybe an index on the DATE column, I personally would choose a condition on the DATE itself:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    emp
WHERE
    hiredate >= TO_DATE('01-JAN-1981','DD-MON-YYYY')
    AND   hiredate < TO_DATE('01-JAN-1983','DD-MON-YYYY')
    ;
```

Here, I make sure I capture all `hiredate` values in 1981 by using the `>=` operator and I get all 1982 records by indicating that the `hiredate` be less than the first date in 1983.